# Ampliar campos de formulario de manera dinámica

Tags: jquery

Buenas, estoy haciendo un formulario y quiero que sea dinámico.

Este aparece tras presionar un enlace (simula botón) y tiene diferentes campos a rellenar. Además, **aquí mi duda** , este formulario puede ampliarse según el usuario necesite.

Quiero que al pulsar sobre el "+" de al lado del `input: text` título 1 aparezca los campos de las fila 2 y 3 y que si pulsan al "+" del otro, se añada solo otra fila 3.

¿Como puedo hacer esto?
Yo este formulario inicial lo represento mediante una serie de contenedores que están en el `html` pero estos nuevos deberán aparecer o no, según el usuario decida, por lo tanto no puedo dejar una estructura prefabricada puesto que cada vez cambiará, además cada uno de sus elementos deberán tener `id` diferentes ya que luego tengo que poder actuar con cada elemento ya sea por `CSS`, `PHP`, etc

Espero haberme sabido explicar muchas gracias por toda la ayuda que ofrece esta comunidad. Un saludo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un título general" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo1" />';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Título 1" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo2" />';
    var titulo3 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Ejercicio" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo3" />';
    var titulo4 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Herramienta" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo4" />';
    var titulo5 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Rondas" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo5" />';
    var titulo6 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Repeticiones" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo6" />';
    var titulo7 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Propuesta de peso" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo7" />';
    var titulo8 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Peso usado" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo8" />';

    var cerrarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="Inputs-Modal" id="cerrar-modal-btn" />';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Guardar-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirObjetivo = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal" id="AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirEjercicio = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal" id="AnyadirEjercicio-modal-btn" />';


    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#ModalFila1').append(titulo1);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(titulo2);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo3);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo4);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo5);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo6);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo7);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo8);

    $('#ModalFila4').append(cerrarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila4').append(guardarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(anyadirObjetivo);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(anyadirEjercicio);

    $('#AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn').click(function() {
      alert('Ahora habría que insertar de nuevo las filas 2 y 3')
    });

  });

});
```

```css
#Modal-Escribir-Rutina {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #21211d;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

  <div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina">
    <div id="ModalFila1"></div>
    <div id="ModalFila2"></div>
    <div id="ModalFila3"></div>
    <div id="ModalFila4"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tienes una idea.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Anyadir-Rutina-btn').click(function() {

    // Hacemos aparecer la ventana modal donde rellenamos formulario.
    $('#Modal-Escribir-Rutina').css({
      'display': 'flex',
      'height': 'auto',
      'width': '80%'
    });

    // Creamos las variables donde se describen todos los elementos del formulario
    var titulo1 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Introduce un título general" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo1" />';
    var titulo2 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Título 1" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo2" />';
    var titulo3 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Ejercicio" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo3" />';
    var titulo4 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Herramienta" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo4" />';
    var titulo5 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Rondas" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo5" />';
    var titulo6 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Repeticiones" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo6" />';
    var titulo7 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Propuesta de peso" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo7" />';
    var titulo8 = '<input type="text" placeholder="Peso usado" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Titulo8" />';

    var cerrarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="Inputs-Modal" id="cerrar-modal-btn" />';
    var guardarModalBtn = '<input type="button" value="Guardar" class="Inputs-Modal" id="Guardar-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirObjetivo = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal" id="AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn" />';
    var anyadirEjercicio = '<input type="button" value="+" class="Inputs-Modal" id="AnyadirEjercicio-modal-btn" />';


    // Insertamos los elementos para que el usuario rellene el formulario
    $('#ModalFila1').append(titulo1);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(titulo2);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo3);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo4);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo5);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo6);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo7);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(titulo8);

    $('#ModalFila4').append(cerrarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila4').append(guardarModalBtn);
    $('#ModalFila2').append(anyadirObjetivo);
    $('#ModalFila3').append(anyadirEjercicio);

    $('#AnyadirObjetivo-modal-btn').click(function() {
      var contador = 0;
      alert('Ahora habría que insertar de nuevo las filas 2 y 3')
      $('#Titulo2').css({
        'display': 'flex'
      });
      $('#Titulo3').css({
        'display': 'flex'
      });
    });


  });

});
```

```css
#Modal-Escribir-Rutina {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #21211d;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#Titulo2,
#Titulo3,
#Titulo4,
#Titulo5,
#Titulo6,
#Titulo7,
#Titulo8 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Power-Contenedor">

  <a href="#" id="Anyadir-Rutina-btn"> Añadir entreno </a>

  <div id="Modal-Escribir-Rutina">
    <div id="ModalFila1"></div>
    <div id="ModalFila2"></div>
    <div id="ModalFila3"></div>
    <div id="ModalFila4"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```